# Let $f(x)=\frac{1+x}{3+x^2} (x\in \mathbb{R})$. Find its Chebyshev norm $\|f\|_\infty$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x)=\dfrac{1+x}{3+x^2}\,\, (x\in \mathbb{R})$. Find its Chebyshev norm $\|f\|_\infty$

The definition of the Chebyshev norm is $\|f\|_\infty = \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|f(x)|$

Using the definition $|f(x)|\to0$ for $x =\pm \infty$

Concluding $\|f\|_\infty= 0$

Comment: The norm is obviously not zero. Finding the maximum is a quick exercise in calculus and finding critical point(s).

Comment: Sorry, you are correct @T.Bongers, the maximum of the function is 1?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, the maximum is not $1$.

Comment: Embarrassing.. what i meant to say was $1/2$? @T.Bongers

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The maximum is at $x = 1$, and is $1/2$. However, you also need to know the absolute minimum in order to compute the norm.

Comment: The derivative of the given function is $$-\frac{{\left(x + 3\right)} {\left(x - 1\right)}}{{\left(x^{2} + 3\right)}^{2}}\ ,$$ and at the two points $-3,1$ the given function takes respectively its absolute minimum $f(-3)=-1/6$, and its absolute maximum, $f(1) = 1/2$. We have $|-1/6|< |1/2|$. So $$\|f\|_\infty=\frac12\ .$$

Comment: Hi @dan_fulea I have another question I hope you don't mind helping... Let $f(x)=(x^2-2x+2)e^{-x} (x\in[0,\infty)) $ Find its Chebyshev Norm $||f||_{\infty}$ I understand this doesn't have a global maximum, how do i go about solving this?

Comment: Just ask before i have to catch the train...

Comment: Assuming I didn’t ask in time @dan_fulea

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{f(t-1)}=\frac{t^2-2t + 4}{t}=t+4/t-2$$ with minimum absolute value $2$ at $t=2$, so the answer is $1/2$ (at $x=1$).